# In Node.js how to notice a missing function?

Tags: node.js, undefined

In some Node.js, I had

```
function examp() {
    ..
    blah = bestAvailableDelauneySlot()
    ..
}
```

However the function `bestAvailableDelauneySlot` did not exist at all.

(In my case I had foolishly forgotten to type the module, so, it should have been `blah = triangles.bestAvailableDelauneySlot()` ..)

Now, the code

```
  blah = bestAvailableDelauneySlot()
```

doesn't create any error AT ALL, until, for some reason `examp` is called at runtime. (Which only happens in obscure situations, once a week).

VSCode does not at all tell me there is no definition for `bestAvailableDelauneySlot`.  "using strict" does not seem to help.

How the heck to safeguard against  an undefined function name??

A simple typo

```
blah = triangles.bestAvailableDelauneySlozz()
```

and crash.  Solution?

Perhaps ideally something that integrates w/ VSCode?

(BTW I generally use VSCode on a Mac ... perhaps that's the problem :O )

Comment: the solution is to make tests, or at least test the obscure code still runs before merging

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - astonishing; so there's no common package, tool, whatever that discovers such likely problems ?!?!  thx.

Comment: How can you be sure the method does not exist? It could be created at runtime.

Comment: @xehpuk - for sure, just like calling a function starting with plain text or the like in a more strongly guarded language.  However, it seem incredible there isn't a tool that - for example - just as you suggest, would alert one "THAT FUNCTION WOULD HAVE TO BE CREATED AT RUNTIME" ... you know?!  I've never seen an IDE that doesn't do that; maybe I just need a different IDE or such ?!?  thx again

Comment: ... but take a look at [ESLint](https://eslint.org/).

Comment: Relying on an IDE to find these types of programming problems in an untyped language like Javascript is just a failed strategy.  You either need unit tests or you will want to switch to a typed language that enforces definitions at compile time (such as TypeScript) or both.  What you have run into is Javascript.  That's how it works (or doesn't work in this case).  It may also be that a linter would help flag this too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) is the de facto standard to check for problems in JavaScript code.

In your specific case, the rule [`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) would report the undeclared function.

There's also an [extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) with more than 12 million downloads:

[image: ESLint for Visual Studio Code applied to the example]

Comment: rule 'no_undef' - what an incredible tip. thanks.  would you say I can use the "no_undef rule" in the VSCode variant??  bounty en route ...

Comment: @Fattie I'm not a regular user of VSC but it should work just fine when the project is set up correctly. I added a screenshot with your example.

Answer (score 3):

I want to provide two methods. I hope it could help you. More detail in [Type checking JavaScrip](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript).
Note: this is vscode.

### First

You could simply add `// @ts-check` in the head of file to validate.   Before you add `// @ts-check`, it doesn't tell you an error (bestAvailableDelauneySlot doesn't exist).

[image]

Then you add `// @ts-check`, it will tell you it doesn't exist.

[image]

Then you declare the function, the error is gone.

[image]

If you make some typo, it will show error message.

[image]

And it also work in module.exports and require. No `// @ts-check`.

[image]

Add `// @ts-check`.

[image]

### Second

If you don't want to add `//@ts-check` by every file, you could create `jsconfig.json` in project root to enable whole files checking with adding `checkJs` in `jsconfig.json`. Its effect is same as adding `//@ts-check` in all files.

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "checkJs": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```